# Induced Bernoulli measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, lebesgue-measure

Given a sequence of Bernoulli trials with paramater $p$. We have by Kolmogorov's extension theorem, a probability measure $P^\mathbb{N}$ on the space of binary sequences. Now letting $P$ denote the measure on $[0,1]$ that corresponds to $P^\mathbb{N}$ if we represent numbers in their binary representation. I would like to prove that $P((0,x])$ is continuous. Furthermore, since each $0<p<1$ induces a new measure $P_p$. Is it always true that these measures are mutually singular?

For the latter, I need to construct disjoint sets $A_p$ such that $P_p(A_p)=1$ and $P_p(A_q)=0$ for $p\ne q$. But I am unsure how to do this. I believe LLN is useful but we have uncountable many measures.

I have got $P((0,x])=\sum_n \frac{x_n}{2^n}$ where $x\in[0,1]$ is represented in binary by $(x_n)_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $f:[0,1] → \mathbb R$ the function in question:

$$f (x) := \mathbb P \big((0,x]\big).$$

Firstly, I am not convinced your formula at the end of the question holds: i.e.,

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{x_n}{2^n},$$

since the right hand side equals $x$! And this is far too rigid: indeed, $f(1/2) = p$ is not necessarily equal to $1/2$.

### Part 1

Let's take another approach:

For simplicity, fix $x \in (0,1)$; the endpoints can be dealt with similarly.

The important thing is that $f$ is monotone increasing; therefore both the limit from below

$$f(x^-) := \lim_{\epsilon → 0^+} f(x - \epsilon)$$

and the limit from above

$$f(x^+) := \lim_{\epsilon → 0^+} f(x + \epsilon)$$

exist (this can be deduced from the completeness axiom for monotone sequences).

Moreover, $f$ is discontinuous at $x$ if and only if these limits are distinct: $f(x^-) < f(x^+)$; this is a a so-called [jump discontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Jump_discontinuity).

To delve deeper:

$$\begin{align} f(x^-) := \lim_{\epsilon→ 0^+} f(x - \epsilon) &= \lim_{\epsilon → 0^+} \mathbb P \big((0,x-\epsilon]\big)  \\&\stackrel\ast= \phantom{\lim_{\epsilon → 0^+}{}}\mathbb P \left(\bigcup_{\epsilon > 0}\; (0,x-\epsilon]\right)\\&= \phantom{\lim_{\epsilon → 0^+}{}} \mathbb P \big((0,x)\big),\end{align}$$

where the equality marked by $\ast$ is [continuity from below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Continuity_from_below). Similarly,

$$\begin{align} f(x^+) := \lim_{\epsilon→ 0^+} f(x + \epsilon) &= \lim_{\epsilon → 0^+} \mathbb P \big((0,x+\epsilon]\big)  \\&\stackrel\ast= \phantom{\lim_{\epsilon → 0^+}{}}\mathbb P \left(\bigcap_{\epsilon > 0}\; (0,x+\epsilon]\right)\\&= \phantom{\lim_{\epsilon → 0^+}{}} \mathbb P \big((0,x]\big)\\&=:\; \phantom{\lim_{\epsilon → 0^+}{}} f(x). \end{align}$$

Therefore, these two one-sided limits are equal (to $f(x)$) if and only if

$$\mathbb P (\{x\}) = 0.$$

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^∞ \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$. Then

$$\sum_{n = 1}^∞ \frac{a_n}{2^n} = \sum_{n = 1}^∞ \frac{x_n}{2^n}$$

implies either that

- $a_n = x_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$; or
- $x = j/2^N$ for some $N\in \mathbb N$ and odd number $j$:
  $$ x = \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{x_n}{2^n},\quad x_N=1\quad \text{and}\quad a_n = \begin{cases} x_n, & n < N, \\ 0, & n = N, \\ 1, & n > N \end{cases}$$
  (i.e., just like $1 = 0.9999\ldots$, but in binary).

Both of these are probability $0$ events, so you're done: the left and right limits exist and are equal to $f(x)$, so the $f$ is continuous at $x$.

### Part 2

For $p \in [0,1]$, consider the set of all sequences where $1$s appear with asymptotic frequency $p$, $A_p$:

$$A_p := \left\{(a_n)_{n=1}^∞ \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\, \bigg|\, \lim_{N → ∞}\underbrace{\vphantom{\bigg|}\frac{\#\big\{n \in \{1,2,\ldots, N\} : a_n = 1\big\}}{N}}_{S_N}  = p \right\}$$

---

**Claim:** For all $p \in [0,1]$, $$\mathbb P_p (A_p) = 1.$$

**Proof:** Fix $p$, And let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ denote a sequence of iid Bernoulli trials (i.e. a random element in the space). Then

$$S_N = \frac 1N \sum_{n=1}^N \boldsymbol 1 _{a_n=1} = \frac 1N \sum_{n=1}^N a_n$$

is the average of the first $N$ trials. Therefore by the Law of Large Numbers, $S_N$ converges almost surely to the expected value of one trial, $p$. In other words, $A_p$ has full measure, $\mathbb P (A_p) = 1$.

---

**Claim:** for all $p\neq q$, $A_p$ and $A_q$ are disjoint.

**Proof:** $(a_n) \in A_p \implies S_N → p \implies S_N \not → q \implies (a_n)\not \in A_q$, and vice versa.

---

**Claim.** Let $p\neq q$. then $\mathbb P (A_q) = 0$

**Proof:** Since $\mathbb P (A_p) = 1$ and $A_p$, $A_q$ are disjoint:

$$ 1 + \mathbb P_p(A_q) = \mathbb P_p (A_p) + \mathbb P_p (A_q) = \mathbb P_p (A_p \sqcup A_q)) \leq 1,$$

i.e. $\mathbb P_p(A_q) \leq 0$.

Comment: what do you mean by $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a random variable in $P^\mathbb{N}$. Wouldn't the sequence $(a_n)$ be an event? For part 2, we can represent $S_N$ by $S_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \mathbf{1}_{a_n=1}$ which does satisfy LLN (but why does it go to $p$?) And I also do no get the disjoint-ness of the sets.

Comment: In order: $$\ $$
1. What I mean is, take $$(a_n) \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N},$$ i.e. an element of the space you've put a distribution on, not necessarily a random variable an event. Do ignore my faulty vocabulary — I'm not a probabilist. I'll correct it to make it more clear.
$$\quad $$
2. I think you'll find that

$$\boldsymbol 1 _{a_n=1} = a_n,$$

each $a_n$ are independent, identically distributed random variables. The LLT may make more sense now.
$$\quad$$
3. If a quantity converges to $p$, it cannot converge to $q$, and vice versa.

Comment: Okay but my issue comes from how the measures relate to the events. For instance, we should have $P_p(A_p)=1$ and $P_q(A_p)=0$. The uniqueness of the limits you have said makes sense but I not understand what $P_p(A_q)$ is as a measure of a set? all of the conditions of the set $A_p$ hold a.e and thus have measure 1 always. Where does the measure used come in ($P_p$ vs $P_q$)?

Comment: In the fact that it gives all of its measure to one element means that the other must get zero: see edited answer for full disclosure.

Comment: Alright for the continuity part, why are we doing this notion of $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{2^n}=\sum_n\frac{x_n}{2^n}$? And I do not get which events you describe have probability 0 (the different cases of $x$ depending on $a_n$?) I do not think this approach is correct as if $p=1/2$ we should recover the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Can we do something along the lines of each $x$ has a unique decimal expansion and thus there exists one sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $x=\sum_n\frac{x_n}{2^n}$? (this is kind of what you did, I believe). However, not I do not know the measure of singletons in the product measure? that is why is $P^{\mathbb{N}}((x_n)_n))=0$.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, in that it is exactly what the above answer says! Except we're talking about binary expansions, and positive rational numbers always have two expansions (think of 0.999…, which is here 0.111…). Indeed:

$$ P^{\mathbb N}(\{x\}) =P_p^{\mathbb N} \left\{(a_n)_{n=1}^∞ \; | \; \sum \frac{a_n}{2^n} = x \right\},$$

and the set on the right consists of just one or two elements (by your or my reasoning). It has measure zero (because any one sequence has measure zero, by"continuity from above") and, as shown above,  this is absolutely equivalent to the continuity of $f$!